# How To Merge Two MP3 Files in Java and Play the result in Windows Media Player?

Tags: java

In the Below Code Two mp3 files are merged but merged audio file is only played in VLC media player, and not in windows Media Player.

```
import java.io.*;
public class TwoFiles
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fistream1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Temp\\1.mp3"); 
        FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Temp\\2.mp3");//second source file
        SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1, fistream2);
        FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\final.mp3");
        int temp;
        while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1)
        {
            fostream.write(temp);   // to write to file
        }
        fostream.close();
        sistream.close();
        fistream1.close();
        fistream2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message of WMP? Can you share the merged file such that we can try it out on our machines? MP3 is a compressed format, I'm pretty impressed that VLC can play your file since your *merging* simply concatenates the contents of both files. Probably all meta-data of the file are corrupt.

Comment: I don't think this "merging" considers what an MP3 format is.

Comment: It's not the compression, as such, that is the problem, because each MP3 frame is (or should be) self-contained. You can actually concatenate raw MP3 data streams. However, because most MP3 files are now encoded with variable bit-rate, it's become common to write a header that indicates the uncompressed length of the file, since it isn't easy to work out from the size. If such a header exists, some players will respect it, and only play that much, even if there is more data. Some, I guess, will just refuse to play anything if the headers are a gross mismatch for the file size.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth checking whether the output file is the expected length, so that the two files have actually been concatenated. However, many media players won't accept an MP3 file like this -- there are all sorts of frame headers that end up in the wrong place, not to mention ID3 tags, etc. It's a tribute to the robustness of players like VLC and mplayer that they can actually handle MP3 files that are so poorly-structured.

The "proper" way to handle this situation is to stream out the actual audio data, and then add back the tags, etc., as required. This is a bear, frankly, and a quick-and-dirty approach that I have found to work quite well is to run `mp3val` on the concatenated files. `mp3val` can (usually) repair the errors caused by crudely joining two files, and is available for many platforms.

Comment: any other way to merger two mp3 files?

Comment: Sure. Strip out all the header and tag information from each file, concatenate the two files, then put some headers and tags back. That's effectively what `mp3val` does. That's a general problem in programming, isn't it ? -- use somebody else's code or write your own :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Zoom Library To Convert MP3 File to WAVE File then Combine Both WAVE File and then By Using jave-1.0.2.jar Convert the combined WAVE File to MP3 File.

//Convrert Mp3 To Wavw

```
Converter myConverter = new Converter();
myConverter.convert("D://1476501067.2281665_0.mp3","D://1476501067.2281665_0.mp3"+".wav");
```

//Combine Both Wave Files

```
 File sample1 = new File("F://StaticVoice.wav");
                                        File sample2 = new File("F://ChangeVoice");
                                           File fileOut = new File("F://MyTest.wav");//WAVEFiles

                                         AudioInputStream audio1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sample1);
                                           AudioInputStream audio2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sample2);

                                           AudioInputStream audioBuild = new AudioInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(audio1, audio2), audio1.getFormat(), audio1.getFrameLength() + audio2.getFrameLength());

                                           for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                                               audioBuild = new AudioInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(audioBuild, audio2), audioBuild.getFormat(), audioBuild.getFrameLength() + audio2.getFrameLength());

                                           }

                                           AudioSystem.write(audioBuild, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, fileOut);
```

//Convert WAVE File TO MP3

```
File source = new File("F://Merge.wav");
                             File target = new File("F://Merge.mp3"); 
                                 AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
                                 audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
                                 audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
                                 audio.setChannels(new Integer(1));
                                 audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
                                 EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
                                 attrs.setFormat("mp3");
                                 attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
                                 Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
                                 encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
```